# Using function factories in pyx/pxd files to generate cython function wrappers for C-library

Tags: python, numpy, cython, python-c-extension

I am re-evaluating different ways to wrap external C libraries into Python. I had chosen long ago to use the plain Python C API, which was fast, simple, standalone and, as I thought, future-proof. Then I stumbled upon `PyPy`, which apparently does not plan on supporting the CPython API, but might become an interesting alternative in the future... I am thus looking for a higher-level entry point. `ctypes` was slow, so now I am back at `cython`, which appears to make an effort to support PyPy.

My library has lots of functions with the same signature, so I made extensive use of C preprocessor macros to generate the Python module. I thought this would become a lot more comfortable in cython, since I would have access to the whole Python language. However, I am having trouble writing a factory for my function wrappers:

```
import cython
from numpy cimport ndarray, double_t

cimport my_c_library

cdef my_c_library.data D

ctypedef double_t DTYPE_t

cdef parse_args(ndarray[DTYPE_t] P, ndarray[DTYPE_t] x, ndarray[DTYPE_t] y):
    D.n = P.size
    D.m = x.size
    D.P = <double*> P.data
    D.x = <double*> x.data
    D.y = <double*> y.data

def _fun_factory(name):
    cpdef fun(ndarray[DTYPE_t] P, ndarray[DTYPE_t] x, ndarray[DTYPE_t] y):
        parse_args(P, x, y)
        getattr(my_c_library, name)(&D)
        return y
    return fun

fun1 = _fun_factory('fun1')
fun2 = _fun_factory('fun2')
# ... many more function definitions ...
```

The cython compiler complains: "C function definition not allowed here", referring to the `cpdef` inside `_fun_factory`. What is the problem here? I thought `pyx` files were just like regular python files. Is there a way to get this working, other than the obvious to generate the `pyx` file dynamically from a separate python script, such as `setup.py`?

I was also surprised that cython wouldn't let me do:

```
ctypedef ndarray[double_t, ndim=1] p_t
```

to clean up the code. Why doesn't this work?

I am aware that there are automatic `C -> cython` translators out there, but I am reluctant to make myself dependent on such 3rd party tools. But please feel free to suggest one if you think it is ready for production use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyx` files are not like Python files in the sense that you can match C and Python functions, and there are some constraints on what you can do with a C (`cdef` or `cpdef`) function. For one, you can't dynamically generate C code at runtime, which is what your code is trying to do. Since `fun` is really just executing some Python code after typechecking its arguments, you might just as well make it a regular Python function:

```
def fun(P, x, y):
    parse_args(P, x, y)
    getattr(my_c_library, name)(&D)
    return y
```

`parse_args` will do the same argument checking, so you lose nothing. (I'm not sure whether `getattr` works on a C library that's `cimport`'d, though. You might want to `import` it as well.)

As for the `ctypedef`, that's probably some limitation/bug in Cython that no-one's got round to fixing yet.

Comment: Thanks, so you are saying I get less flexibility from `cython` than from the C preprocessor? That's unexpected... What do you think about the possibility to patch together the `pyx` file in `setup.py`? Lots of large strings involved, but CPP macros aren't exactly pretty either.

Comment: @Stefan: Cython is not a magic bullet for turning C into Python. Rather, it hooks the two together and optimizes some Python code. I wouldn't go generating Cython source files in `setup.py`, that's a maintenance nightmare. How many functions are we talking about?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. As you suspected, `getattr` doesn't work (`import my_c_library` doesn't help). More surprisingly, I can't even pass `my_c_library.fun1` as a second argument to the factory: "Cannot convert 'data *' to Python object".

Answer (score 0):

After playing around some more, the following appears to work:

```
def _fun_factory(fun_wrap):
    def fun(P, x, y):
        parse_args(P, x, y)
        fun_wrap()
        return y
    return fun

def _fun1(): my_c_library.fun1(&D)
def _fun2(): my_c_library.fun2(&D)
# ... many more ...

fun1 = _fun_factory(_fun1)
fun2 = _fun_factory(_fun2)
# ... many more...
```

So there seems to be no possibility to use any Python operations on expressions like `my_c_library.fun1(&D)`, which apparently need to be typed as is. The factory can be used only on a second pass when one already has generated a first set of Python wrappers. This isn't any more elegant than the obvious:

```
cpdef fun1(ndarray[DTYPE_t] P, ndarray[DTYPE_t] x, ndarray[DTYPE_t] y):
    parse_args(P, x, y)
    my_c_function.fun1(&D)
    return y

# ... many more ...
```

Here, `cpdef` can be used without problems. So I'm going for the copy-paste approach... Anyone also interested in preprocessor macros for Cython in the future?